# Performance between while(1) and blocking call

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, mq

I have a little app that consumes messages from RabbitMQ.

Currently its in a while(1) loop, it calls "Dequeue" and wait there forever for a message and then handles the message.

So i was thinking  is  the blocking call "Dequeue" a good idea or would a immediate DequeueNoWait(nothing there return immediate) not be better or even maybe a "Dequeue" with a timeout. There would of course be much more while iterations.

thanks

Comment: A spin wait should only be used if the expected time to wait is "very short". You're effectively keeping the CPU busy with nothing. In the case where doing this is cheaper than doing a context switch to another thread then it might be a good idea. If you wait for a long time it is not. Without knowing more about your case it is hard to give good advice. Do you have async versions of those methods?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not have async. That would have been very nice.

Comment: @Pintac it is very easy to write an async wrapper. Obviously an I/O thread must be sacrificed. But this is normal/acceptable and common in EDA (Event Driven Architecture, for example node.js). So the idea of an async wrapper is more about programming style and ease of use than performance or resource footprint.

Comment: Yeah if this was a very huge/important part to my system i would have most probably done one but seeing that this is a small maintenance task its really not worth the effort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic problem. The best you can do is use a blocking `Dequeue()` with timeout so that more than just RabbitMQ messages can be processed. For example:

- on Unix/Linux also process system signals such as SIGHUP or SIGINT
- on terminal commands also accept user input to break out of the loop with a message "Press ESC to quit..." or something similar
- if there are other input streams process those, too, in the same thread

The timeout should be set based on what you expect. For some system signals very strict timeouts are given before the process is blasted out of the water. For a console applications human users will not notice a 150 ms timeout, it will still look near-to-realtime to them.

If you don't block and don't use a timeout the CPU will consume unnecessarily resources to just loop through as fast as possible, without any benefit. Something like this is only advisable when timing is extremely important. But then you wouldn't use RabbitMQ either.

---

EDIT: more about the timeout

> A 1 second timeout does **not** mean that a message is picked up in 1 second. Messages are still processed instantly, as they arrive. The timeout means that *OTHER* tasks are performed with at most 1 second delay (mean delay is half the timeout, so 0.5 seconds).

Comment: Yeah i was leaning towards  timeout. An in my case its a maintenance task that nobody looks at and if it takes 1s before a message gets picked up that is alright no rush :-)

Comment: Yip its the most it will wait for a message.